# Sonar: is there a way to add custom rules for python using Java

Tags: python, sonarqube

According to documentation there're 2 ways to include custom rules:

- Writing coding rules using Java via a SonarQube plugin
- Adding XPath rules directly through the SonarQube web interface

According to [link](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Adding+Coding+Rules) sonar-python doesn't support the first way which I would like to use.

I wonder whether something is changing and this feature is going to be supported? If this feature is supported where can I find a tutorial which is like a tutorial [for Java](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Writing+Custom+Java+Rules+101)? Or is there only one way to create own Sensor and use implemented python-parser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing custom rules for SonarPython using java is not supported.
Currently there's no initiative to enable it.
But if the rules are not specific to your context and can be useful to every python code, you can contribute by writing descriptions and non-compliant/compliant code examples in this google group:
 [groups.google.com/sonarqube](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sonarqube), or you can create a pull request on [github.com/SonarSource/sonar-python](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-python).